# Sudoku generator in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, unique, permutation, sudoku

I'm trying the following code to generate a 3x3 sudoku,

```
[*1..3].permutation.uniq{
    _1.index(1) && _1.index(2) && _1.index(3)
}
```

I'm trying to pass multiple condition in `uniq` method, but I can't do so. I've seen other SO post in which they suggest,

```
uniq{[cond1, cond2, ...]}
```

But, it doesn't work, tried `||` too.

I think `&&` takes only the last, whereas `||` takes only the first condition, as both of them are truthy!

How to solve this?

---

Expected output:

```
3x3 sudoku like:
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

The order of numbers in above sudoku doesn't matter.

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ – what is the code supposed to achieve? What's your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan - I'm supposed to generate a [sudoku](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paul_Roach2/publication/264572573/figure/fig1/AS:295976259604480@1447577647208/An-Example-Sudoku-Puzzle-and-its-Solution-1.png) in which every rows/columns sums upto 45 (in case of 9x9).

Comment: I'm referring to your `uniq` call that _"doesn't work"_. What is it supposed to return?

Comment: @Stefan - Oh, okay. Basically, I don't know how to do it, but I'm trying to use those three parameters in uniqueness, somehow. Like, if any permutation has any number at same index, then drop that one.

Comment: `[*1..3].permutation` yields 6 permutations – which of those do you want?

Comment: @Stefan - I've edited my post to include expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to use those three parameters in uniqueness, somehow. Like, if any permutation has any number at same index, then drop that one.

I doubt that you can generate a sudoku using `uniq` because the method operates on a single element at a time without taking the other elements into account.

You could use a loop to remove those values.

You start by generating all permutations: (I'm using a 4×4 sudoku for demonstration purposes)

```
permutations = [*1..4].permutation.to_a
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3, 2],
#    [2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [2, 4, 3, 1],
#    [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 2, 1, 4], [3, 2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1],
#    [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

From this array, you pick a random element as the first row:

```
row_1 = permutations.sample #=> [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

You then remove all elements that have `3` in the 1st spot, or `2` in the 2nd, `1` in 3rd, or `4` in 4th:

```
permutations.delete_if { |row| row_1.zip(row).any? { |i, j| i == j } }
#=> [[1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3, 2],
#    [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1],
#    [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

From the remaining array, you can pick another random element as the second row and start over:

```
row_2 = permutations.sample #=> [2, 3, 4, 1]

permutations.delete_if { |row| row_2.zip(row).any? { |i, j| i == j } }
#=> [[1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3, 2],
#    [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2]]

row_3 = permutations.sample #=> [1, 4, 3, 2]

permutations.delete_if { |row| row_3.zip(row).any? { |i, j| i == j } }
#=> [[4, 1, 2, 3]]

row_4 = permutations.sample #=> [4, 1, 2, 3]   (or permutations.last)
```

The resulting `row_1`, `row_2`, `row_3` and `row_4` are: (printed as a sudoku)

```
╔═════╤═════╗
║ 3 2 │ 1 4 ║
║ 2 3 │ 4 1 ║
╟─────┼─────╢
║ 1 4 │ 3 2 ║
║ 4 1 │ 2 3 ║
╚═════╧═════╝
```

You might notice that although rows and columns only contain unique numbers, the 2×2 subgrids contain duplicates. It is therefore *invalid*.

---

You could probably add another condition that takes the subgrids into account, but there are much easier ways to **generate a valid sudoku**. Here's one:

You generate a random valid first row, e.g.:

```
row_1 = [*1..4].shuffle #=> [3, 4, 2, 1]
```

For the 2nd row, you rotate the first row by 2: (the subgrid size)

```
row_2 = row_1.rotate(2) #=> [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

For the 3rd and 4th row, you rotate the first row by 1 and 3 respectively:

```
row_3 = row_1.rotate(1) #=> [4, 2, 1, 3]
row_4 = row_1.rotate(3) #=> [1, 3, 4, 2]
```

Printed as a sudoku:

```
╔═════╤═════╗
║ 3 4 │ 2 1 ║
║ 2 1 │ 3 4 ║
╟─────┼─────╢
║ 4 2 │ 1 3 ║
║ 1 3 │ 4 2 ║
╚═════╧═════╝
```